# How to use the SPEC benchmark (for dummies)

Tags: benchmark

I just had a quick look so far at the documentation of the SPEC2006 benchmark. However, until now I was not able to find some information how I can nicely present the performance measurements I got from the benchmark. So I am wondering if some of you have played around with it and can lead me where I could find a "SPEC2006 for dummies". Basically, I wanna run all the benchmarks, for int as well as fp, and I wanna display (visualise) then the performance values for all the different benchmarks in one graph. I guess there must be a way to do that easily, cant imagine that I have to copy all the timings results from the single benchmarks.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The closest I have been able to find is [this](http://www.ptlsim.org/capswiki/index.php/SPEC_2006) page from a wiki. It may be too specialized for your use.